# How can I run several PHP scripts from within a PHP script (like a batch file)?

Tags: php

How can I run several PHP scripts from within another PHP script, like a batch file?  I don't think include will work, if I understand what include is doing; because each of the files I'm running will redeclare some of the same functions, etc.  What I want is to execute each new PHP script like it's in a clean, fresh stack, with no knowledge of the variables, functions, etc. that came before it.

**Update**: I should have mentioned that the script is running on Windows, but not on a web server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the [exec()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function to invoke each script as an external command.

For example, your script could do:

```
<?php

exec('php -q script1.php');
exec('php -q script2.php');

?>
```

Exec has some security issues surrounding it, but it sounds like it might work for you.

Comment: what does -q do?  Is it relevant still?  I was looking up man pages and it executes it quietly.   What does that mean?  Supresses output or something?

Answer (score 6):

// use exec http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
<?php

exec('/usr/local/bin/php somefile1.php');
exec('/usr/local/bin/php somefile2.php');

?>
```

In the old days I've done something like create a frameset containing a link to each file. Call the frameset, and you're calling all the scripts. You could do the same with iframes or with ajax these days.

Answer (score 3):

exec() is a fine function to use, but you will have to wait until termination of the process to keep going with the parent script.  If you're doing a batch of processes where each process takes a bit of time, I would suggest using popen().

The variable you get creates a pointer to a pipe which allows you to go through a handful of processes at a time, storing them in an array, and then accessing them all with serial speed after they're all finished (much more concurrently) using steam_get_contents().

This is especially useful if you're making API calls or running scripts which may not be memory-intensive or computationally intensive but do require a significant wait for each to complete.

Answer (score 3):

If you need any return results from those scripts, you can use the [`system`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function.

```
$result = system('php myscript.php');
$otherresult = system('php myotherscript.php');
```